# Issue with building project in XCode -- ProcessPCH Error

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, prefix

I've been having an issue compiling my project after attempting to install the Facebook SDK to the project. I've reverted the code back to it's previous state, however I'm still getting error messages related to "ProcessPCH". I've checked the Target settings and still cannot find any solution to this issue.

The error code is shown below:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/AirFranceMusic-Prefix-acpjajeiwlvgzwgddsqkamtwztjy/AirFranceMusic-Prefix.pch.pth AirFranceMusic/AirFranceMusic-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Intermediates/AirFranceMusic.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AirFranceMusic.build/AirFranceMusic.hmap -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Intermediates/AirFranceMusic.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AirFranceMusic.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Intermediates/AirFranceMusic.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AirFranceMusic.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src --serialize-diagnostics /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/AirFranceMusic-Prefix-acpjajeiwlvgzwgddsqkamtwztjy/AirFranceMusic-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/AirFranceMusic-Prefix.pch -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/AirFranceMusic-Prefix-acpjajeiwlvgzwgddsqkamtwztjy/AirFranceMusic-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AirFranceMusic-btdgsdavrzffuyaockrkcyvdacgq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/AirFranceMusic-Prefix-acpjajeiwlvgzwgddsqkamtwztjy/AirFranceMusic-Prefix.pch.d

In file included from /Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/AirFranceMusic-Prefix.pch:20:
In file included from /Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/../../libs/MKNetworkKit/MKNetworkKit.h:52:
/Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/../../libs/MKNetworkKit/Categories/NSString+MKNetworkKitAdditions.h:26:1: error: missing '@end'
@interface NSString (MKNetworkKitAdditions)
^
@end

/Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/AppDelegate.h:16:1: note: class started here
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
^
In file included from /Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/AirFranceMusic-Prefix.pch:20:
In file included from /Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/../../libs/MKNetworkKit/MKNetworkKit.h:52:
/Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/../../libs/MKNetworkKit/Categories/NSString+MKNetworkKitAdditions.h:26:21: error: method type specifier must start with '-' or '+'
@interface NSString (MKNetworkKitAdditions)
                    ^
/Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/../../libs/MKNetworkKit/Categories/NSString+MKNetworkKitAdditions.h:26:22: error: expected a type
@interface NSString (MKNetworkKitAdditions)
                     ^
/Users/admin/Documents/AirFranceMusic/src/AirFranceMusic/../../libs/MKNetworkKit/Categories/NSString+MKNetworkKitAdditions.h:28:1: error: expected selector for Objective-C method
- (NSString *) md5;
^
4 errors generated.
```

If anyone has a solution for this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to delete the derived data in the organizer tap Projects?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to delete the derived data. Also tried to re-install XCode and also create a new project and import the files into it, all resulting the same error, which makes me believe it must be some error within one of the header/implementation files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is now fixed. While I'm not proud with myself for causing the issue, I am very glad it is solved.

**In my case, I had accidentally commented out the @end of my AppDelegate header file, causing the XCode project to fail building entirely.**

I'm still very unsure as to why it was then stating my failure was related to a file within MKNetworkKit, but I can only suggest that you check ALL of your files for common mistakes like this if cleaning the build / derived data does not work. Reinstalling XCode is definitely not an ideal solution.

Comment: Just as a tip. Use version control like git or svn. You can compare changes and spot these kind of mistakes easier. I recommend SourceTree.

Comment: Good point zeiteisen. I tend use to git on other projects when working with multiple developers, but couldn't really justify using git on a solo project up until now. So from now on, I'll stay safe and make a repo every time.